# Using tactics with the Z3 optimizer and the C++ API

Tags: c++, optimization, z3

I'm using the Z3 optimization functionality through the C++ API and would like to modify the tactics being used in an attempt to reduce the amount of time it takes Z3 to find satisfying models.  I've run into two major problems with this:

1. [While you can build a `solver` from a tactic](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c%2B%2B/example.cpp#L597) it doesn't appear that you can do the same thing for an `optimize` object.
2. I don't know exactly what the right tactics to use are, so I would like to start by modifying whatever is being used be default.  This will let me explore different strategies and try out different combinations.  The problem is that I don't see any way to ask the solver for it's currently configured tactics.

Does anyone know how to create an `optimize` object from a set of tactics, or how to mimic one using the right tactic combinations?  Is there a command I can use (even for the command line tool) that will cause it to display the tactics currently being used?

For a little extra background information, I'm mainly interested in adding [`par-then` and `par-or`](http://rise4fun.com/Z3/tutorial/strategies) combinators and removing any tactics that don't have to do with Booleans, integer arithmetic, and `if-than-else` expressions.

Comment: You can get some information about what tactics are in use from the command-line tool by specifying `-v:10`.  Also, the order of tactics applied by default when `(check-sat)` is used can be found in [src/tactic/portfolio/default_tactic.cpp](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/tactic/portfolio/default_tactic.cpp).  I don't know where the equivalent code is for the optimization routines.

Also, I recommend cloning and compiling the current version of Z3 from GitHub. There were a few bugs related to both the optimization and the parallel combinators that have been fixed since v4.4.1.